# Как вывести номера всех минимальных нечётных элементов массива?

Tags: c++, массивы

Пусть дано:Вывести номера всех минимальных нечетных элементов. Нумерация
начинается с нуля. Если таких элементов нет, то вывести сообщение об
этом.n =8 Массив =0, 5, 9, 1, 2, 7, 1, 3 Результат = 3 6
n =8 Массив= 2, 6, 10, 6, 8, 8, 8, 2 Результат = нечетных элементов нет
Вот мой вариант:

```
//вывести номера всех минимальных нечётных элементов массива
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int n;
    cout << "Введите размерность массива - ";
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "]= ";
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int min = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0) 
        {
            if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];
        }
        else if (a[i] == min)
            cout << "Номера всех минимальных нечётных элементов равна " << n;
        cout << endl;         
    }
    if (min % 2 == 0)
        cout << "не чётных элементов нет/n" << endl;
    cout << min << endl;
    delete []a;
    return 0;
}
```

Что тут не верно?Помогите исправить пожалуйста.Не серчайте,я только учусь работать с массивами...Задача всё ещё не решена.

Comment: При коде Zhihar,у меня выводит при 0, 5, 9, 1, 2, 7, 1, 3 что нечётных чисел нет,а это не правильно

Answer (score 1):

ошибка у вас в том, что вы определяете минимальный элемент и выводите на экран минимальный элемент ОДНОВРЕМЕННО, что неверное

вам сначала надо

1. найти минимальный нечётный элемент с помощью одного цикла
2. вывести минимальные нечётные элементы с помощью второго цикла

т.е.

```
int min = a[0];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    min = ((a[i] % 2 != 0) && (a[i] < min)) ? a[i] : min;
}

if (min % 2 == 0)
    cout << "не чётных элементов нет/n" << endl;
else
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        if (a[i] == min)
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: то есть первый цикл проверка на нечетность,а второй цикл что тогда?

Comment: первый цикл - поиск минимального нечетного элемента - найти вы его можете только просмотрев все элементы в массиве, поэтому для этого и нужен цикл

второй цикл - когда вы знаете минимальный элемент массива теперь можно опять пройти по всем элементам массива и вывести позиции

посмотрите код, я приложил

в вашем же кода если бы была последовательность '9 7 5 3 1' вы бы выводили бы `0 1 2 3 4`, потому что каждый последующий элемент меньше предыдущего, а это неверная логика ибо в этой последовательности минимум - это `1`

Comment: Zhihar ,понятно.Спасибо,у меня получается уже лучше чем раньше,и вопросов меньше задаю:)

Comment: если вы еще выучите пошаговую отладку - еще 90% отпадет - вы пошагово сможете проходить по программе своей и видеть где какие значения получаются и почему - очень полезная вещь

Comment: Zhihar,я пошаговую отладку знаю только в Паскаль ABC и C# а с ++ не знаю.

Comment: Это странное заявление. Если человек в курсе, что отладка существует, и применяет её, то какая разница, что за язык используется (при наличии IDE)

Answer (score 0):

В общем я решил все проблемы с вашей помощью и своим умом предоставляю к ознакомлению полный код для решения данной задачи.

```
//вывести номера всех минимальных нечётных элементов массива
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int n;
    cout << "Введите размерность массива - ";
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    cout << "Введите " << n << " целых чисел:\n";
    int min_odd = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i] % 2 && (min_odd == INT_MAX || a[i] < min_odd)) min_odd = a[i];
    }
 
    if (min_odd != INT_MAX)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == min_odd)
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else cout <<"нечётных элементов нет/n"<<endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

Работает и выводит верный результат:)